# Call method by name using an attribute value as methodname php

Tags: php, syntax

Firstly here is a code example which works:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $name = "test";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $name = $this->name;
        $this->$name();
    }

    function test()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
$foo = new Foo();
?>
```

Now, my question is: Is it possible to directly use the artribute name of the class Foo to call the method test without creating a new variable like this:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $name = "test";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$name();
    }

    function test()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
$foo = new Foo();
?>
```

Looking forward for your answers,
Heeiiigou

Comment: Hm, why don't you just call `$this->test()` in your constructor? Anyway, `$this->{$this->name}();` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in {} like so:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->{$this->name}();
}
```

Comment: Nice, Thx this works just fine. Can you tell me background, why this is working?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php for the details